# How to print only Date and Time (not seconds) in C# in efficient way?

Tags: c#, time, datetime-format

I'm using `LastWriteTime` property for a file which I use, to print the last modified time. 
However, here when I use I get a value like

> "2/12/2011 11:58:45 AM".

(i) Can you pls help to ignore seconds here meaning the output should be like:
    **2/12/2011 11:58 AM**

(ii) Also, how do I ensure that I'm taking care of time zones as in the file LastWriteTime   could be as per other GEO timings. Can you pls help to take care of this?

(iii) Also how to take care of Culture problems here as CurrentCulture would be different for machines?

Comment: Check [this.][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4415824/remove-hourssecondsmiliseconds-in-datetime-object

Comment: I think what @LoganLehman is trying to say is "Check [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4415824/remove-hourssecondsmiliseconds-in-datetime-object)"

Comment: it would be good to have examples of what you mean in your question list specifically

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**The patterns for DateTime.ToString ( 'g' ) :**

```
0    MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm    08/22/2006 06:30

1    MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm tt 08/22/2006 06:30 AM

2    MM/dd/yyyy H:mm     08/22/2006 6:30

3    MM/dd/yyyy h:mm tt  08/22/2006 6:30 AM
```

Source: [DateTime.ToString Patterns](http://www.geekzilla.co.uk/View00FF7904-B510-468C-A2C8-F859AA20581F.htm)

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `g` format to represent the date as you wish:

```
 string date = File.GetLastWriteTime("file").ToString("g");
```

As for the `TimeZone`, `DateTime` doesn't contain relevant `TimeZone` information. You'll have to handle this yourself.

Maybe this will help you:
http://hashfactor.wordpress.com/2009/02/02/c-parsing-datetime-with-timezone/

Comment: [`LastWriteTime`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.filesysteminfo.lastwritetime.aspx) is a `DateTime` property, so this is not the case