# c# DateTime won't sort correctly in DataGridView from Access DB

Tags: c#, sorting, datetime, ms-access, datagridview

I have an issue with sorting dates in DataGridView, i am adding data to access db like this

```
DateTime act_date = DateTime.Today;
DateTime op_date = dateTimePicker1_txt.Value.Date;

command.CommandText = "insert into data (client,operation,op_time,ac_user,actual_date,operation_date,price) values('" + client_box.Text + "','" + operation_box.Text + "','" + time_txt.Text + "','" + emp_box.Text + "','" + act_date + "','" + op_date.ToShortDateString() + "','" + price_txt.Text + "')";
```

and then load data to datagridview, in database it look fine, i can sort like a date, but in DGV is always sorted like a number e.g.

16.12.2015 0:00

26.4.2016 0:00

31.3.2016 0:00

4.2.2016 0:00

i have to use central europe format
i want to hide the minute and second, but it work just when i put data to database like a string
i am loading dgv like this this.dataTableAdapter.Fill(this.akmv_dbDataSet.data);
DGV look like this
https://i.stack.imgur.com/YxzcC.png

please help, i am lost

Comment: Can you share some more code? I have the feeling that your datagrid columns are not in the correct format.

Comment: i am loading dgv like this this.dataTableAdapter.Fill(this.akmv_dbDataSet.data);

Comment: Can you show the layout of your DataGridView?? The columns that is. And please add this to your initial question so others can see it more easier as well. (Will increase  the amount of responses)

Comment: format of date column look like this https://i.imgur.com/qfXHHkH.png

Comment: Here are [Link1](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7235324/datetime-format-in-asp-net-gridview) and [Link2](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4415824/remove-hourssecondsmiliseconds-in-datetime-object) to help your Minutes and seconds problem.

Comment: You should _never_ store your `DateTime` values as a `string`. And always use parameterized queries. This kind of string concatenations are open for SQL Injection attacks.